# #pragma pack(show) with GCC

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, gcc

Is there a way to show the memory "pack" size with GCC ?

In Microsoft Visual C++, I am using:

```
 #pragma pack(show)
```

which displays the value in a warning message; see [Microsoft's documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e70t5y1.aspx).

What is the equivalent with GCC?

Comment: I don't see one in [the documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Structure-Packing-Pragmas.html).

Comment: @Elias: What's wrong with the [tag:c] tag?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Given that the OP is coming from VC++, and has tagged this question C++, too, I suspect the code he's writing is written in C++, not C. The preprocessors should be the same, but that hasn't always been the case

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem: But the OP apparently wants to know about both C and C++, and the functionality is the same for both. But yes, it's important to remember that C and C++ are two different languages. OP: Are you really using both C and C++?

Comment: This is one of those rare instances in which I think both tags are fine, but YMMV :)

Answer (score 2):

Since I can't see such functionality listed in [the pertinent](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html#Diagnostic-Pragmas) [documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Structure-Packing-Pragmas.html), I'm going to conclude that GCC cannot do this.

Comment: Though you can not do this, maybe the c++11 offsetof helps, depending on the situation. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/offsetof It should be good enough for e.g. unit tests.  (I never used it, so I am not sure if it works as expected with packing on.)

Comment: @meandbug: Yeah, possibly

Answer (score 2):

I use a static assertion whenever I pack a structure and want to see its size.

```
/*
   The static_assert macro will generate an error at compile-time, if the predicate is false
   but will only work for predicates that are resolvable at compile-time!

   E.g.: to assert the size of a data structure, static_assert(sizeof(struct_t) == 10)
*/
#define STATIC_ASSERT(COND,MSG)      typedef char static_assertion_##MSG[(!!(COND))*2-1]
/* token pasting madness: */
#define COMPILE_TIME_ASSERT3(X,L)     STATIC_ASSERT(X,at_line_##L)             /* add line-number to error message for better warnings, especially GCC will tell the name of the variable as well */
#define COMPILE_TIME_ASSERT2(X,L)     COMPILE_TIME_ASSERT3(X, L)               /* expand line-number */
#define static_assert(X)              COMPILE_TIME_ASSERT2(X, __LINE__)        /* call with line-number macro */

#define PACKED  __attribute__ ((gcc_struct, __packed__))

typedef struct {
  uint8_t bytes[3];
  uint32_t looong;
} PACKED struct_t;
static_assert(sizeof(struct_t) == 7);
```

This will give you a compile time warning whenever the static assertion fails.